# How to run a process elevated on Windows?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm using a windows API call to create a process in a simple account as an administrator using [`CreateProcessWithLogonW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithlogonw):

```
CreateProcessWithLogonW('admin',
                        nil,
                        'Pa$$w0rd',
                        LOGON_WITH_PROFILE,
                        'cmd.exe',
                        nil,
                        0,
                        nil,
                        nil,
                        Si,
                        Pi);
```

but sometimes it returns

> Error 5 Access denied

and when it does not, it does not run it as administrator even if that account is an administrator

Comment: I'm guessing you mean it does not run elevated when it works?

Comment: yes , even if the specified account is an administrator

Comment: That is just how UAC works.

Comment: yep , but this function should run the application with specified credentials

Comment: And it does, but the integrity level (elevation) is not tied to the credentials nor whether or not you are a member of the administrators group.

Comment: so according to u how can I achieve i

Comment: I want to bypass UAC, how can I do it? You can't. But I want to. How can I do it? You can't. I still want to. Argh!!!!

Comment: BTW u , for your information bypassing UAC could be done using tool called UACME , first understand the question before posting your silly comment

Comment: Since you don't mind being flagged as malware you can use uacme itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the process to be elevated (or the process requires elevation) you cannot do that with CreateProcessWithLogon.

I am not able to test that right now but I think you need to:

1. Call [LogonUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera) to get the primary token
2. Call [GetTokenInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671(v=vs.85).aspx) with the [TokenLinkedToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ne-winnt-_token_information_class) Information class to get the linked (Elevated) token.
3. Call [CreateProcessAsUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx) with the linked token.

Comment: but CreateProcessAsUser  requires priveleges to be aquired and these funnctions returns acces denied on simple accounts

Comment: That's how UAC works, you can only solve that by using a service

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind UAC kicking in (but I fear that you do), then you can simply do, for example:

```c
HINSTANCE hInst = ShellExecuteW (NULL, L"runas",
    L"notepad.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutew) for values returned in `hInst`.  Sorry the example is in C++ but I'm sure you can translate.

If you want to circumvent UAC then you must indeed launch your application from a service in order to have it run elevated.  Sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50743993/5743288), again in C++, sorry, and it could use a little polishing up but it certainly works.  I assume you want to run the process in the context of the currently logged-in user as that code does.  Please vote that answer up (or this one, or both) if it helps U.

---

**Edit:** (as the OP is still evidently struggling with this).

You know what?  I could give you chapter and verse on how to solve this problem *but I'm not going to*, because you would just build one big, huge security loophole when your software was installed.  That too is soluble, but would you actually bother?

Anyway, put yourself in your users' shoes for a moment.  How do you think *they* will feel when a program starts doing things that can normally only be done by a program running as Administrator without first displaying the expected UAC prompt?  If it was me, I would freak out.

So no, just use the `ShellExecute` trick I first recommended and leave it at that.  It's more than good enough.

Comment: this will bring the prompt asking for admin priveleges , but I want to run it with admin credentials that i already have

Comment: Then you will have to write a service, it's not hard.  Please refer to the code I linked to.

Comment: well I'm creating a Launcher that launches my application which required admin priveleges to change the domain name of users that belongs to the domain , users should not be admin , or be given admin credentials, so I must do it that way

Comment: Well, sorry to have to tell you this (again), but you can't.  It's a service or nothing.  Does your launcher have an installer?  If so, you can run that installer elevated and install the service then.  To do this, check out the `SC` command, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47006989/5743288 (and no doubt other similar information sources on the 'net).

Comment: @user3374161 then use a deployment/configuration tool to do this such as SCCM  which are designed to handle such functionality

Answer (score 0):

I believe that one can achieve the end goal of running a process as another user as well as being elevated by using an intermediate bootstrapper application.

Use `CreateProcessWithLogonW` to create a process with the other user's credentials but instead of running the target application, you could create another application that exists only to create an elevated process, or call the current application with some arguments specifying that you want to elevate the target application (something like `--elevate C:\Windows\Notepad.exe`). This process would (running as the other user) use the `runas` verb in a `ShellExecute` to launch the desired application.

```
Runner.exe uses CreateProcessWithLogonW(user,pass)
=> (to run)
Runner.exe --elevate C:\App.exe uses ShellExecute(runas)
=> (which gives)
App.exe (running as user + elevated)
```

You would get a UAC prompt *but that is how Windows works now and it should not be circumvented*.

For my money that's way easier than creating a service that you then have to communicate with etc.

You can read about this [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/why-can-8217-t-i-elevate-my-application-to-run-as-administrator/ba-p/228626) (Windows Blog Archive: Why Can’t I Elevate My Application to Run As Administrator While Using CreateProcessWithLogonW?) It's a bit old, but it's still valid. Happy to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with a service you can run an application with specific admin credentials, but please be aware this will create other undesired side effects. So I think you’re better of trying to review your use case: do you really need a simple non-admin user to have an application run elevated with every security hole you can think of…. My answer is NO absolutely not. Usually you can setup things during install (with admin rights) and sometimes give specific user groups some rights to modify parts (Like folder rights). But that’s it.

So many users keep asking this same question, but simple everything you try is just something that’s getting close to hacking Windows and that’s just plain bad.

If you really don’t want UAC to kick in, then disable it for the machine! But I don’t think you want that…