# Create process from service

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-services, ghostscript

I'm calling GhostScript(GS) command line tool from C++ code with WinAPI CreateProcess function. When I'm running my application as 'common' executable file, everything works fine, but when I'm running my app as service, something goes wrong - GS process creates and it's listed in task manager processes list but then nothing happens. If I run my application as a service on Windows 7 it works correctly, but on Windows 10 the above problem occurs. Code listed below. I will be grateful for any advice.

```
std::string cmd = ("gswin32c.exe -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -dNoCancel=true -sOutputFile=\"%printer%HPLJ2000\" \"1.pdf\"");
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;`sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
auto dwFlags = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL;
STARTUPINFOW si;
GetStartupInfoW(&si);
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

if (!CreateProcess(NULL, cmd.c_str(), NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
    std::err << "Something went wrong" << std::endl;
}

WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

Comment: The problem may be related to the user account (and its privileges) used to start the service (by default "System"). If GS provides a log or some other info written to file, you can analyze it to search for issues.

Comment: You are using current working directory relative file names. Don't do that. The current working directory is outside your control, and failure to open a file is just one of the many ways it can manifest itself.

Comment: begin from `CreateProcessAsUserW`, duplicate your process token, set here `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()` and create new process with this token on `"Winsta0\\Default"` desktop. not hide window. and not pass additional parameters(enter it manually). look which will be effect and based on this move to some side. also in your current code `WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);` senseless and bad. and for what you set `bInheritHandle = TRUE;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your process is probably running on the wrong desktop.

There's a bunch of stuff you need to do to fix this.  Full example code here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50743993/5743288